# Nginx rewrite rule with permanent and last flags

Tags: nginx, rewrite

Is it possible to use multiple flags in one Nginx rewrite rule, like permanent+last ?

Answer (score 0):

No. But there is no need to. Any flag will cause the rewrite module to stop processing rewrite directives within the current context.

The **permanent** flag forces *external redirection*, and the **last** flag forces *internal redirection* - so the two flags are mutually exclusive anyway.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.